# how can i add cookie's code in my web application

Tags: java, cookies

Is there any code that I could add in my web application in order to implement cookies?which is the exactly way that I can do that in web.xml and in jsp maybe?I want to implement cookies for login,but I have no idea how I can do that .Could anyone give me exact instructions on how to implement it?

Thank you very much for help and support.

```
/*
```

* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package my_servlets;

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;  

import connect_with_my_sql_database.LoginDao;
```

import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;

```
public class Login extends HttpServlet{  

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)    
            throws ServletException, IOException {


    }

  @Override protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)    
            throws ServletException, IOException {    

        response.setContentType("text/html");    
       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();   

        String n=request.getParameter("j_Username");    
        String p=request.getParameter("j_Password");   

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);  
        if(session!=null)  {
             session.setAttribute("Username", n);  
             session.setAttribute("Password", p);  
        }

        if(LoginDao.validate(n, p)){   

            Cookie c1=new Cookie("j_Username",encrypt(n));//the username and passwrd are //encrypted
            Cookie c2=new Cookie("j_Password",encrypt(p));
            c1.setMaxAge(20000);
            c2.setMaxAge(20000);
            response.addCookie(c1);
            response.addCookie(c2);

            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("style/success.jsp"); 
            rd.forward(request,response);    
        }    
        else{  
           //out.print("<p  style=\"color:red\">Sorry "+n+" or "+p+" error</p>");
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("style/loginError.jsp");    
            rd.forward(request,response);    
        }    


        out.close();    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why are you tagging this with `javascript` if you want to do a login system? Are you writing a Node.js application? If so, then your HTTP API probably has methods for dealing with cookies.

Comment: yes ,sorry ,you are right.It may be better to tag this with cookies or something like that. I am not writing a node.js application

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume there is a login.jsp having fields for uname and password, and when we hit the submit the control goes to LoginCheck servlet. LoginCheck will check if username and password is correct. If yes it is creating two cookies and sending them to browser.

Login.jsp

```
<form action="LoginCheck" method="post">
<input type="text" name="uname">
<input type="pasword" name="password">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

LoginCheck-- Servlet

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
{
String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
String password=request.getParameter("password");
if(checkLogin(uname,password))//checkLogin going to check with database if the user is logged in
{
Cookie c1=new Cookie("uname",encrypt(uname));//the username and passwrd are //encrypted
Cookie c2=new Cookie("password',encrypt(password));
c1.setMaxAge(20000);
c2.setMaxAge(20000);
response.addCookie(c1);
response.addCookie(c2);//sends cookies to the browser
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can i see in practise ,though , that cookies work right?what should be appeared when i login my application?I am beginner in web applications and my questions may be  a bit trivial or stupid

Comment: After setting the cookies through the above code that is in LoginCheck you may like to check if the cookies has been set. To check you may use Cookie arr[]=request.getCookies(); then you may iterate through the Cookie array .    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){String name=arr[i].getName(); String value=arr[i].getValue();}  Hope it helps.

Comment: i have added my servlet code above, is it right? where can i add tha iteration of the array?in my servlet or in a new jsp?